# Why Python Logging Created 2 Log Files

Tags: python, logging

I have below Python code to log activities

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')

log_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), 'logs', today, 'refresh_'+timestamp+'.log')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    filename=log_file,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name).4s %(process)6d/%(threadName)s: %(levelname).4s %(message)s')

def func_1(args):
    if abc:
            logging.info('--- Refreshing ['+fn+'] completed ---')
        except:  
            logging.critical('--- Refreshing ['+fn+'] failed! ---')
    else:
        logging.critical('--- Retrieving ['+fn+'] data failed! Error:' + str(page.status_code) + ": " + account + ": " + password + '---')

    return;

def func_2(file_path):
    logging.info('Loaded all connecting metadata successfully')
    return;

if __name__ == '__main__':

    func_2(abc)

    pool = Pool(processes=threads)
    pool.map(func_1, abc)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    logging.info('--- Whole process completed ---')
    logging.shutdown()
```

The problem is that the process created 2 log files with different time (as I used time-stamp down to seconds in the file name). One log file `log_1` logged all activities in `func_1` and got generated first. The other one `log_2` logged `Loaded all connecting metadata successfully` from `func_2` and `--- Whole process completed ---` from the end of the code; it got generated last.

I suspect it is due to the fact that there are 2 handlers and each handler gets generated at different time. How can I make sure all activities are logged to one log file instead of 2?

Comment: I didn't get your problem. If you are logging to files with the name as timestamp then there will be multiple files. What do you expect?

Comment: @AmitTripathi I need all activities to be logged into one log file (e.g. refresh_2017_12_18_11_08_18.log)